# How to make a SharePoint Forms as a default

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, custom-form

I have created a NewForms.aspx for a SharePoint list and I am wondering how I can make this new page default when users click on the new option.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - After custom form is created**:

Follow Below Steps:

1. Click on the form name.
2. Click on the **FORMS** from top ribbon.
3. Select **Set as Default**.

[image]

**Solution 2 - While creating a new custom form**:

1. Click on **New** in the **Forms** section from designer to create new custom form.
2. On form settings check the **Set as a default form for the selected type** checkbox to make your form as a default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Ganesh

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.